# Иконки в трее KDE

Tags: linux, skype, fedora, kde

Недавно пересел на Fedora 22 с kde, и столкнулся с тем, что в трее не появляются иконки запущенных приложений (skype/dropbox/etc). Под ubuntu с unity был пакет, решающий эту проблему для скайпа - skype-wrapper, но для fedora и kde решения не нашел, по этому вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в трее отображались иконки программ, запущенных в фоне?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте поставить пакет `sni-qt:i386`, либо `sni-qt:i686`. У меня данный пакет исправил проблему в `Debian sid, KDE 5`.

Answer (score 0):

вот [здесь](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=282195) и [здесь](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=282028) пишут, что проблема в некоем `task manager` (`system monitor`?) и если заменить его на другой, то иконки у некорректно пакетированных программ — появятся.